# Does SuperUser have a spam problem

Tags: discussion, spam

I asked a question recently and had a few spam answers. All by people with 1 rep as well... Don't know if it was because I had put a bounty on the question and they didn't know how it worked but I just wanted to know if SuperUser had a spam problem before I start to frequent here.

Case in point: [Explorer Hidden Taskbar Breaks](https://superuser.com/questions/729410/explorer-hidden-taskbar-breaks/731327?noredirect=1#731327)

Comment: Its a known troll, he turns up periodically and posts under multiple false identities. Its not a big issue, just one guy

Comment: The community here is great at flagging spam posts or even deleting them outright. There's no spam *problem* on the site, even though we have the occasional spammer -- nonsense like these posts survive a few hours at most. You've really just been unlucky -- the vast majority of questions on this site have no (deleted) spam or nonsense answers.

Comment: Stack Exchange is also constantly improving their spam detection tools, which automatically throttle posts which are more likely to be spam. I expect we'll see less from this spammer soon ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have as much of a spam problem as the whole internet does.

That being said, no, we don't *really* have a spam problem. We have a couple of spam posts per day. A couple of non-sense posts as well, but it's not like we're drowning in it.

Even the trolls like the one you linked in your question are usually squashed within an hour or so. Nothing really stays up long.

Comment: Thanks. Only reason I ask is because I've been on Stack Overflow for a year now and haven't experienced trolls or spammers before. Maybe I'm just lucky.

Comment: Just worth mentioning, SU is directly behind (actually not far behind) from SO as being the most spammed site on the network. The system rejects about 60,000 posts per 7 day period, most in the form of suggested edits.